# Recieving 502 when requesting url that executes mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

The request takes a long time and eventually fails with `502` error.

You can see `app.get('/players'` is invoked but the db query never prints results.

`collections` in `lastmanstanding` db ..

```
> use lastmanstanding
switched to db lastmanstanding
> show collections
openshift
players
system.indexes
system.users
```

`console.log` ..

```
Listening on 127.2.202.129:8080
Connected correctly to server
/players requested
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1",
    port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080,
    mongoDbUrl = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL || 27017,
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    assert = require('assert'),
    ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
    url = mongoDbUrl + 'lastmanstanding';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");

    db.close();
});

// home requested
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

// players requested
app.get('/players', function(req, res) {
    console.log('/players requested');
    var findPlayers = function(db, callback) {
       var cursor = db.collection('players').find();
       cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
          assert.equal(err, null);
          if (doc != null) {
             console.log(doc);
             res.send(doc);
          } else {
             callback();
          }
       });
    };
});

// start server
app.listen(port, ipaddress, function () {
    console.log('Listening on ' + ipaddress + ':' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you've defined the function that calls the mongodb but are not calling that function when you receive the request. You need to call your findPlayers function when you receive the request for the response to be sent